# How can I calculate the distance between two coordinates using road networks in R without the Google Maps API

Tags: r, distance

I would like to calculate the distance between these points below, considering the **road network**, but I don't want to use the Google Maps API specifically, it can be another one. Do you have any suggestions on how to do this? These are the coordinates I have:

```
coords<-structure(list(Latitude = c(-22.8851078223344, -22.8315940282463
), Longitude = c(-48.4939312250395, -48.4298167144681)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: This is probably too broad a question for a Stackoverflow answer, but you can do this with offline OpenStreetMap downloads and the osrm package - see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/osrm/ and http://project-osrm.org/ - it is a pretty involved procedure however. If you are only doing a handful of coordinates, you can use the osrm demo server to do this online.